# Find polynomial $q(x)$ whose values match a known polynomial $p(x)$ with matching values except one.

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

Here is the full problem statement:

> The polynomial $p(x)=x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1$ has the following values:
> $(-2,31)$, $(-1,5)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,1)$, $(2,11)$, $(3,61)$.
>
> Find a polynomial $q(x)$ that takes the following values:
> $(-2,31)$, $(-1,5)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,1)$, $(2,11)$, $(3,-59)$.

I know I can find the polynomial $q(x)$ by the finding the interpolating polynomial using the given data values, but I also know that I should be able to use $p(x)$.

A hint was given saying that this problem can be solved with little work, so how would I use $p(x)$ to solve?

Comment: Hint I haven't tried. Find a polynomial that's $0$ at the points where nothing changes, has value the difference you want at the other point, and add the polynomials.

Comment: $q(x)=p(x)-(61-(-59))\dfrac{(x-2)(x-1)x(x+1)(x+2)}{(3-2)(3-1)3(3+1)(3+2)}$

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a polynomial that has $0$'s in the points $-2$ to $2$ and equals $(-120)$ at $3$. This means, to the original polynomial you have to add a multiple of $(x+2)(x+1)x(x-1)(x-2)$. Since $(3+2)(3+1)3(3-1)(3-2) = 120$, the answer is
$x^4 - x^3 + x^2 - x^1 + 1 - (x+2)(x+1)x(x-1)(x-2)$. You may recalculate the coefficients yourself.

P.S. The polynomial is not unique, since any polynomial which has zeros at the points $-2$ to $2$ and is nonzero at $3$ would do. All you need is to scale your polynomial accordingly.